# How can i get reponse back from service without delay in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I call the service method from the controller it returns data with delay and I need this response to populate the dropdown

EXPECTATION :
When I call this method from the controller it should return a response immediately then other logic should run after this.

Service Code

```js
app
    .service('UserAccounts', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
       
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var allInvoices;
        this.vendorPromise = $http.get('api/invoices/getAllinvoices', { params: { cache: false } }).then(
            function (response){
                Invoices = response.data;
                deferred.resolve(Invoices);
            }).catch(function (err){
           

        });

        
        this.findUserByNameEmail = function (Name, email) {
            if (allInvoices) {
                return $q.when(allInvoices.filter(function (vendor) {
                    return user.ReceivingLegalName == Name && user.ReceivingEmail == email ;
                }));
            }
            else {
                var findDeferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.promise.then(function (Invoices) {
                    findDeferred.resolve(Invoices.filter(function (user) {
                        return user.ReceivingLegalName == Name && user.ReceivingEmail == email ;
                    }));
                });
                return findDeferred.promise;
            }
        };
        
     

    }]);
```

Controller code :

```js
UserAccounts.findUserByNameEmail($scope.invoice.userName, $scope.invoice.email).then(
                        function (invoiceDetails) {
                            
                         $scope.InvoiceList = invoiceDetails;
                            
                        });
```

when I try to do it like this it returns a response immediately but gets value inside $$state

```
$scope.InvoiceList = UserAccounts.findUserByNameEmail($scope.invoice.userName, $scope.invoice.email);
```

[image]

Looks like .then takes some time to return response .could some one help me here

See below code

I have Test and Test1 which is getting called from UI.$scope.test 1 depedns on  $scope.InvoiceList but i get $scope.InvoiceList response from $scope.test after $scope.test 1 completed.

```
$scope.test = function ()
{

UserAccounts.findUserByNameEmail($scope.invoice.userName, $scope.invoice.email).then(
                        function (invoiceDetails) {
                            
                         $scope.InvoiceList = invoiceDetails;
                            
                        });
                        

}

$scope.test 1  = function (){
//some logic based on $scope.InvoiceList 
 $scope.finallist ; 

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with delay? It looks like you’re going to an API, which takes time. I also deleted the Angular tag from this question.

Comment: You have a bunch of asynchronous code here which generally doesn't run in the order that it's written.  You have to use constructs like async/await which do a pretty good job of simulating "wait for this async thing to finish before executing the next line of code".

Comment: @James can you please help me to make this code Async/Await?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common thing to do and you will always have at least 50ms delay when you fetch data from an API

What you will have is the initial value of null or undefined for your data variable
And when the data is done being fetched from the API, you set the data variable with the res.data
In your View, you can have a check to see if you have data yet. If there is no data, display a little spinner or loading text to the user

So something like this:

```
let data = [] or null

//when your View loads, you do the data call to your API
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(YOUR_API_URL)
    if (res.status === 200) {
      data = res.data
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
    //you also have the option of setting an error message in your View
  }
}
```

Now in your View you can have a check to see if your data is populated yet after calling the API:

```
{data && data.length > 0 ? data.map(DO_RENDERING) : <span>Loading...</span>}
//You can also just check if the data isn't equal to null
```